# Deploy Nodejs app on cPanel using Application Manager

Tags: node.js, apache, centos, cpanel, whm

I am trying to deploy my Nestjs-based application on cPanel (centOS) with Apache.

I followed steps mentioned here =>  https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

I want to deploy it on a subdomain. So I have /home/myUserName/public_html/mySubDomain folder, in which I have my Nestjs files.

Created application with Application Path as `public_html/mySubDomain/dist/src`

I have added

```
<Location "/">
    <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerAppEnv "production"

        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerBaseURI "/"
        PassengerAppRoot "/home/myUserName/public_html/mySubDomain/dist/src"
        PassengerAppGroupName "myUserName - appName"
        PassengerRuby /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/libexec/passenger-ruby27       
PassengerPython /usr/bin/python
        PassengerNodejs /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/node
        # PassengerAppRoot /home/public_html/mySubDomain
        PassengerAppType node
        # Set PassengerStartupFile variable
        PassengerStartupFile /home/public_html/mySubDomain/dist/src/main.js
    </IfModule>
</Location>
DocumentRoot /home/myUserName/public_html/mySubDomain
<Directory "/home/myUserName/public_html/mySubDomain/dist/src">
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    Options -Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/myUserName/mySubDomain/appName.conf`

After following I am getting an error

`Error: Cannot find module '/home/public_html/mySubDomain/dist/src/main.js'`

Can anyone please help me and suggest what could be wrong? Thanks